# MySQL query performance improvement

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with performance with MySQL. How can i improve it?
The situation is following:

- Table “backlogsap„ have about 4 mio entries.
- Indexes are created
- This table have FK and other tables have FK to this table => can’t
  create partitions.
- This query need about 140 seconds to complete:

  ```
  select 
      idmaterial,
      materialgroup, 
      materialgroupcategory,
      name,
      dispatchgroup,
      idsupplier, 
      group_concat(distinct sellingorganizationname) as sellingorganizationnames,
      group_concat(distinct idordertype) as idordertypes,
      group_concat(distinct idpositiontype) as idpositiontypes,
      sum(newOrUpdated and isCritical) as classA,
      sum(newOrUpdated and not isCritical) as classB,
      sum(processingstate <3) as classC,

      (select count(innerBacklogsAp.idmaterial) 
          from backlogsap as innerBacklogsAp
          where innerBacklogsAp.idmaterial = src.idmaterial and IsDeleted = 0) as countReplacementVehiclerRequests

  from 
      (select 
          backlogsap.idmaterial as idmaterial,
          backlog.processingstate as processingstate,
          material.idsupplier as idsupplier,
          backlogsap.sellingorganizationname as sellingorganizationname,
          backlogsap.idpositiontype as idpositiontype,
          backlogsap.idordertype as idordertype,
          materialindistributioncenter.dispatchgroup as dispatchgroup,
          material.name as name,
          material.idmaterialgroup as materialgroup,
          materialgroup.idmaterialgroupcategory as materialgroupcategory,
          (processingstate = 0 or processingstate = 1) as newOrUpdated,
          ((cancellation.state is not null and cancellation.state = 0 ) or
               (reminderrequest.state is not null and (reminderrequest.state = 2 or reminderrequest.state = 0))
              ) as isCritical
      from backlogsap 
      join backlog using (idbacklogsap)
      left join cancellation using (idcancellation)
      left join reminderrequest on backlog.IdReminderRequest = reminderrequest.idreminder
      left join material using (idmaterial)
      left join materialindistributioncenter using (idmaterial, iddistributioncenter)
      left join materialgroup using (idmaterialgroup)

       where (idcancellation is null or cancellation.State not in (1)) and
           backlogsap.isdeleted = 0 and
           backlogsap.idordertype not in ('ZAP', 'ZAK', 'ZAKO', 'ZAKZ', 'ZAPM') and
           iddistributioncenter = 1469990
      ) as src
  group by idmaterial
  order by classA desc, classB desc, classC, idmaterial desc
  ```
- Explain

  ```
  id  select_type         table                           type            possible_keys                                           key                                                                 key_len     ref     rows    Extra
  1   PRIMARY             <derived3>                      ALL                                                                                                                                                             26960   Using temporary; Using filesort
  3   DERIVED             backlogsap                      index_merge     PRIMARY,fk_BacklogSap_OrderType1_idx,
                                                                          fk_BacklogSap_MaterialInDistributionCenter1_idx,
                                                                          perform_backlogsap_isdeleted,
                                                                          fk_BacklogSap_DistributionCenter_idx                    perform_backlogsap_isdeleted,fk_BacklogSap_DistributionCenter_idx   1,4                 35946   Using intersect(perform_backlogsap_isdeleted,fk_BacklogSap_DistributionCenter_idx); Using where
  3   DERIVED             backlog                         eq_ref          idBacklogSAP_UNIQUE,
                                                                          fk_Backlog_BacklogSap1_idx,
                                                                          fk_Backlog_Cancellation1_idx                            idBacklogSAP_UNIQUE                                                 4           ...backlogsap.IdBacklogSap  1   
  3   DERIVED             cancellation                    eq_ref          PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY                                                             4           ...backlog.IdCancellation   1   Using where
  3   DERIVED             reminderrequest                 eq_ref          PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY                                                             4           ...backlog.IdReminderRequest    1   
  3   DERIVED             material                        eq_ref          PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY                                                             45          ...backlogsap.IdMaterial    1   
  3   DERIVED             materialindistributioncenter    eq_ref          PRIMARY,
                                                                          unqiue_IdDistributionCenter_IdMaterial,
                                                                          fk_MaterialDistributionCenter_DistributionCenter1_idx,
                                                                          fk_MaterialDistributionCenter_Material1_idx             PRIMARY                                                             49          const,...backlogsap.IdMaterial  1   
  3   DERIVED             materialgroup                   eq_ref          PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY                                                             137         ....material.IdMaterialGroup    1   
  2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  innerBacklogsAp                 ref             perform_backlogsap_isdeleted,
                                                                          idx_backlogsap_IdMaterial                               idx_backlogsap_IdMaterial                                           45          func    8   Using where
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: created combined Index (idmaterial, IsDeleted)